# Is there any way to chunk message while sending message into service bus topic in logic app?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a logic app and sedning messages to service bus using `service bus connector`

when a message is more than 1mb i'm getting below error -

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "A request has exceeded the maximum message size for 'demo.servicebus.windows.net' Service Bus namespace and 'demo' entity. Validate the content size before retrying.",
  "error": {
    "message": "A request has exceeded the maximum message size for 'demo.servicebus.windows.net' Service Bus namespace and 'demo' entity. Validate the content size before retrying."
  }
}
```

Is there any way to handle such scenarios ?

Comment: For standard 256KB for Premium 1MB.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-premium-messaging

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you already got the result from the doc I shared:[Service Bus Premium and Standard messaging tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-premium-messaging).

These two tiers of Service Bus Messaging are designed to serve different use cases, however, both of them have a limit about the message size.

- **Premium**: Message size up to 1 MB
- **Standard**: Message size up to 256 KB